# MongoDB query on multiple array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mern

Say I have a mongoSchema of **user** with the following field

```
googleId: String,
name: String,
Language : [{}],
```

User can initially specify an array of language-set [up to 5] on their profile page.

For example, user can have 2 language set as below:

Language :

```
[main: {name: English, code: ko}, secondary: [{name:Japanese, code: jp}, {name:Chinese, code: en}]], 

[main: {name: Korean, code: ko}, secondary: [{name:Japanese, code: jp}, {name:English, code: en}]
```

From this information, I want to render out only the post that matches the following preference.

For example post with **English** to **Japanese**,  **English** to **Chinese** (from first language set)

as well as post with **Korean** to **Japanese**, **Korean** to **English** (from second language set)

My post schema has

```
    postName: String
    original: {},
    target: {},
```

For example,

```
postName: 'Korean to Japanese Post'
original: {name: Korean, code: ko}
target: {name: Japanese, code jp}
```

What should I put inside the curly brackets to fetch the posts with specified language set

```
const prefLang = req.user.Language
const post = await Post.find({ some query using prefLang to check over matching original and target })
res.send(translations)
```

Comment: **(1.)** Is the actual schema of the field `Language` defined as in your code? because  `main: [Object]` would mean array of objects and `[Array]` would mean array of arrays. **(2.)** Also, your in your example, `secondary` should have multiple objects right? currently you have a single objects with duplicate keys. **(3.)** your post schema has original and target, but your did not mention about `user.original` and `user.target` so what is `req.user.original` and `req.user.target`? Isn't it supposed to be `user.Language`?

Comment: 1. Sorry I printed the console.log. In schema it is defined as Language: [{}] 2. Yes it should be multiple [{name: Japanese, code:jp}, {name:Chinese, code: ch}] 3) I should just have const prefLanguage =  req.user.Language. Sorry I'll edit this info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query object should look like this for your example

```
{
  $or: [
    {
      original: { name: "English", code: "en" },
      target: {
        $in: [{ name: "Japanese", code: "jp" }, { name: "Chinese", code: "cn" }]
      }
    },
    {
      original: { name: "Korean", code: "ko" },
      target: {
        $in: [{ name: "Japanese", code: "jp" }, { name: "English", code: "en" }]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

So you will have to construct the condition from `prefLang` like this

```
const query = {
  $or: perfLang.map(lang => ({
    original: lang.main,
    target: { $in: lang.secondary }
  }))
}

const post = await Post.find(query)
```

Tip:

If the language objects have a strict schema, you can define them like this

```
const LanguageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  code: String
}, {
  _id: false
})

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  //...
  googleId: String,
  name: String,
  Language: [{ main: LanguageSchema, secondary: [LanguageSchema] }]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the usage of basic boolean logic would suffice:

```
const prefLang = req.user.Language;

let conditions = [];

prefLang.forEach((langObj) => {
    let tragetLangs = langObj.secondary.map(lang => lang.code);
    conditions.push({
        $and: [
            {
                "original.code": langObj.main.code,
            },
            {
                "target.code": {$in: tragetLangs}
            }
        ]
    })
})

// you should check conditions !== empty array.
const post = await Post.find({$or: conditions})
```

Comment: Wouldn't this only list out the post that matches the first set? I could have up to 5 language set. I want to go over all of them.

Comment: Then I misunderstood the data structure, is `prefLange` a list of those objects as i specified in the comment?

Comment: yes it's a list of the language set object. Sorry i didn't make this clear

Comment: I edited my answer to support an array, the logic is still the similar but we do an `$or` over the conditions built as there can be multiple.

Comment: thanks i'll be able to award bounty in a couple of hours. Just one more question, say if i have an additional field such as specialities (array of object {name: Business, description: blahblah} , {name: IT, description: blahblah}  ) in usershema. Is it possible to sort the post according to these specialty? For example, say user has language set like [main: 'Korean', secondary: {name: 'Japanese' code: 'jp'}, {name: 'Chinese, code:'ch'}] then post that has Korean as original language and Japanese as target Language should be shown but if user also has speciality like 'IT' set up

Comment: then post with 'korean' as original language and 'japanese' as target Language as well as  category with IT should be shown prior to just post with original and target set as korean and japanese respectively. Is this possible through a simple Find? or is this not possible through mongo?

Comment: You can't add a custom sort like that using find, even if you use aggregate you'll still have to manually add a place holder field like `kr_sort: 1, jp_sort: 2` and only then you'll be able to sort on that, i'm going to add a simple aggregation that starts with the user to show it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217690/discussion-between-seoi-min-and-tom-slabbaert).